# js get radio label text

Tags: javascript

i have this code :

```
<input type=radio name="vote_x" value="5">
    <label for="vote_x">blabla</label><br>
```

how can i get the label value for radio with id of `vote_x` [using JS] ??

thanks

Comment: is this straight JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put an id on the label like this

```
<input type="radio" name="vote_x" value="5">
<label id="for_vote_x" for="vote_x">blabla</label>
```

You can then use

```
var textinlabel = document.getElementById("for_vote_x").innerHTML;
```

---

**Edited: With out using an id for the label element**

```
var labelElements = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (var i = 0, var labelElement; labelElements[i]; i++) {
  if (labelElement.getAttribute("for") == "vote_x") {
    //this is the labelElement you want
    //code goes here
  }
}
```

Ideally you would want to create a Generic function for this

```
function getlabelforinput(inputname) {
    var labelElements = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    for (var i = 0, var labelElement; labelElements[i]; i++) {
      if (labelElement.getAttribute("for") == inputname) {
        return labelElement
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: any workaround without the need to create an ID for the label ?

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero....  I added a different solution that will work if you put the label before or after the input element.

Comment: Anyway to get the selected label for a radio button?

Answer (score 1):

## Modern answer

Use `document.querySelector('label[for="INPUT_ID"]')` to get the label element corresponding to the input with given id.

Example:

```js
const label = document.querySelector('label[for="vote_x"]');
console.log(label.textContent.trim());
```

```html
<input type=radio name="vote_x" value="5">

<label for="vote_x">blabla</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var el = document.getElementById("vote_x");
while(el.nextSibling && !(/label/i.test(el.nextSibling.tagName))){
    el = el.nextSibling;
}
var text = el.nextSibling.innerHTML
```

You can check it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f27aS/).

Comment: I guess this would work but maybe the label isn't guaranteed to be the next sibling?

Comment: The loop will take care of the text nodes that may come in between the input element and the label. If the position is not fixed then @John's solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606300/js-get-radio-label-text/4606417#4606355) will be the best one.